# How to use ffmpeg to reduce video length by removing or reducing length of silence in audio channel?

Tags: ffmpeg

How can ffmpeg be used to reduce the length of some long webinar recordings, by removing or reducing the length of pauses or silence, since the speaker on the audio-channel speaks with rather long pauses ?

The nature of video are recordings of technical presentations, so the video is very slow changing projected presentation, and the speaker speaks in a manner where she waits for answers, reaction from attendees, and in a very thoughtful manner. However during playback, this sounds very boring and lengthy.

Please note that I am already aware of the right way to speed up the audio/video using ffmpeg, but here I am not looking to speed up entire video by a constant speed, but only the innumerable periods of silence (say with signal below a certain threshold) on audio track ?

Comment: See [silencedetect](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#silencedetect) or silenceremove filters.

Comment: Thanks llogan. I did come across those 2 audio filters, but couldn't think of any obvious way to also drop the video by same length as the audio silence to keep the audio/video tracks in sync. Let me know if you have any thoughts on how to potentially achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

While I'd prefer a pure ffmpeg way if one exists, but I did find a way that involves a python script that in turn uses ffmpeg.

Here's an opensource project called [JumpCutter](https://github.com/carykh/jumpcutter) which seems to do exactly what I wish to. The original author seems to have abandoned the project in favour of [commercializing it](https://jumpcutter.com/) (and can't blame him, as it seems quite a nifty tool, if one were to watch the demo video). However, [this fork](https://github.com/ThornM9/jumpcutter) of the project seems to be latest and claims to work. I think I have understood how this works, and I might actually try a slightly more efficient method (avoid chopping video up entirely into individual frames, as that makes the process of converting super long videos, painfully slow). If I manage to do it, I will come back and update this answer.

*PS> I will not accept this answer for now and **keep this question open** for better ffmpeg only answers, or methods that might be faster, avoid reencoding etc.*